# Rails 4 - Strong Parameters - Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, parameters

Good afternoon!

I'm attempting to whitelist my params that are coming from my form and I can't seem to formulate the correct hash structure. Here's what I got so far..

In the HTML:

```
<% @type_flag_list.each do |flag| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'activity[flags_attributes][][flag_cd]', flag.flag_cd %><%= flag.flag_ref.description %><br/>
<% end %>
```

In my model:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flags
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :flags
end
```

In my controller:

```
params.require(:activity)
  .permit(
    flags_attributes: [:flag_cd]
  )
```

When I dump out my params in the log file, I see the following:

Params from form look like this (which look exactly how I want it to):

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",authenticity_token"=>"M4pY9K2CECfJpUirHPwHQRRKgCKio+x6H7dGu/IsNNuC/jDqyPOJ4C2XrGJ6ECG9gkvzh0tmzhV/FqHd5pWSmA==", "commit"=>"Save for Later", "activity"=>{"flags_attributes"=>[{"flag_cd"=>"basic_science_research"}, {"flag_cd"=>"clinical_research"}, {"flag_cd"=>"health_policy_research"}, {"flag_cd"=>"med_edu_research"}, {"flag_cd"=>"public_health_research"}, {"flag_cd"=>"translational_research"}]}
```

But when i dump out my whitelisted params, I get the following:

```
{"flags_attributes"=>[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]}
```

It's apparent that the problem resides with the way I am 'permitting' the parameter in my controller, but I've tried many variations and cannot get the values I want to show up like they do in the original form params.

Can anyone help spot the problem or guide me to a direction that will get me the structure I need?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You'll want to rearrange the input name FROM `activity[flags_attributes][][flag_cd]` TO `activity[flags_attributes][flag_cd][]`

Comment: can you `pry` exactly in action end provide `params`?

Comment: @OlegSobchuk I'm not sure what you mean by 'pry'. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @WesFoster That didn't work, when I change the html to that, my params for flags_attributes still come back empty: `flags_attributes"=>[{}]`. In my test case, it should be showing 4 attributes, but there it's one empty brace.

Comment: @Sixers17 do you use `binding.pry` ?

Comment: @OlegSobchuk No I'm sorry I do not.